# Array Formula with N/A to print nicely when empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, printing

We use a rather long formula something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(FILTER(SOURCERANGE!A1:A99999,SOURCERANGE!N1:N99999=A2  ))))
```

Some cells in our table gave results and they print nicely.

But some cells do NOT have results. And they print as `#N/A` ...

I have never quite liked the `#N/A` and would rather show an empty cell or a dash.

The only solution so far that I have found is to add an `ISERRROR()` or `ISNA()` formula around it, but then this feels silly because the initial formula is executed twice.

**Question**: is there an easy way to tell sheets to print `""` instead of `#N/A`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en-GB) OR [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en-GB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your formula with the [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en-GB) function instead:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(FILTER(SOURCERANGE!A1:A99999,SOURCERANGE!N1:N99999=A2)))),"")
```

You could also try the [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en-GB) function.